# What is definition of an Identical Request?

Tags: microservices, terminology, distributed-system

I found a good answer about idompetancy here (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/320143/should-an-idempotent-service-always-return-the-same).

But what really is the definition of "identical request" ?
Can a two different API calls (different requestid/correlationid) but with the exact same body content be considered as identical request ?

My understanding is : it does not matter **when** and **how** (either via api call or event messaging) the two requests are made, as long as they has the same effect to the application state , then both are the same request.    Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the application state stays the same after the requests. How you do idempotency depends on how you want to deal with these type of scenarios.

### Scenario 1

```
increment(x)
```

```
append(xs, x)
```

I highly discourage such an APIs; but they must have a unique correlation id or some sort of admission control to work properly.

```
idempotency token: 521F14B6-4A72-467F-8CD0-6654C69F4629
increment(x);
```

```
append(xs, x)
   where xs read at revision 1022;
```

### Scenario 2

```
Put(x=1)
Delete(x)
Put(x=1)
```

How do you determine if the two `Put`s are the same? Again, either idempotency tokens or admission control or both.

---

A key issue with idempotency tokens is what to do with them. Do they have a TTL? Do you store them in a database?

Comment: we use correlation-id as part of the request header.   but then in some cases, we could be getting the same exact  request body but with diff correlation-id.   we're thinking to implementing a message store to tackle this duplicate request .